# how to improve algorithm efficiency of entropy weight method in python

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy, time-complexity, entropy

Below is the code, however, it's very slow when dealing with large data. (maybe takes >1 days for a **5,000,000 rows, 6 columns** dataframe.

Just wondering how could I optimise it? Many Thanks

```
def ewm(df):
    df = df.apply(lambda x: ((x - np.min(x)) / (np.max(x) - np.min(x))))
    rows, cols = df.shape 
    k = 1.0 / math.log(rows)
 
    lnf = [[None] * cols for i in range(rows)]
    for i in range(0, rows):         
        for j in range(0, cols):
            if df.iloc[i][j] == 0:
                lnfij = 0.0
            else:
                p = df.iloc[i][j] / df.iloc[:,j].sum()
                lnfij = math.log(p) * p * (-k)
            lnf[i][j] = lnfij
    lnf = pd.DataFrame(lnf)
 
    d = 1 - lnf.sum(axis=0)
    w = [[None] * 1 for i in range(cols)]
    for j in range(0, cols):
        wj = d[j] / sum(d)
        w[j] = wj
    
    w = pd.DataFrame(w)
    w = w.round(5)    #.applymap(lambda x:format(x,'.5f'))
    w.index = df.columns
    w.columns =['weight']
    return w
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having numpy do the loops should speed it up alot

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def ewm(df):
    df = df.apply(lambda x: ((x - np.min(x)) / (np.max(x) - np.min(x))))
    rows, cols = df.shape 
    k = 1.0 / math.log(rows)
    
    p = df / df.sum(axis=0)
    lnf = -np.log(p , where = df!=0 )*p*k
    
    d = 1 - lnf.sum(axis=0)
    w = d / d.sum()
    
    w = pd.DataFrame(w)
    w = w.round(5)
    w.index = df.columns
    w.columns =['weight']
    return w
```

Answer (score 1):

use iat instead of iloc when getting specific value
and if you do the same iloc twice save it in a tmp

```
import pandas as pd
import time
import numpy as np
import math

#original method
def ewm(df):
    df = df.apply(lambda x: ((x - np.min(x)) / (np.max(x) - np.min(x))))
    rows, cols = df.shape 
    k = 1.0 / math.log(rows)
 
    lnf = [[None] * cols for i in range(rows)]
    for i in range(0, rows):         
        for j in range(0, cols):
            if df.iloc[i][j] == 0:
                lnfij = 0.0
            else:
                p = df.iloc[i][j] / df.iloc[:,j].sum()
                lnfij = math.log(p) * p * (-k)
            lnf[i][j] = lnfij
    lnf = pd.DataFrame(lnf)
 
    d = 1 - lnf.sum(axis=0)
    w = [[None] * 1 for i in range(cols)]
    for j in range(0, cols):
        wj = d[j] / sum(d)
        w[j] = wj
    
    w = pd.DataFrame(w)
    w = w.round(5)    #.applymap(lambda x:format(x,'.5f'))
    w.index = df.columns
    w.columns =['weight']
    return w


#modified method
def ewm1(df):
    df = df.apply(lambda x: ((x - np.min(x)) / (np.max(x) - np.min(x))))
    rows, cols = df.shape 
    k = 1.0 / math.log(rows)
 
    lnf = [[None] * cols for i in range(rows)]
    for i in range(0, rows):         
        for j in range(0, cols):
            tmp = df.iat[i,j]  #********************************* modified section
            if tmp == 0:
                lnfij = 0.0
            else:
                p = tmp / df.iloc[:,j].sum()  #************************ end of modified
                lnfij = math.log(p) * p * (-k)
            lnf[i][j] = lnfij
    lnf = pd.DataFrame(lnf)
 
    d = 1 - lnf.sum(axis=0)
    w = [[None] * 1 for i in range(cols)]
    for j in range(0, cols):
        wj = d[j] / sum(d)
        w[j] = wj
    
    w = pd.DataFrame(w)
    w = w.round(5)    #.applymap(lambda x:format(x,'.5f'))
    w.index = df.columns
    w.columns =['weight']
    return w



df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(1000,6))
start = time.time()
ewm(df)
print(time.time()-start)

start1 = time.time()
ewm1(df)
print(time.time()-start1)
```

time for first func is 1.9747240543365479

for second its 0.820796012878418

i'm not sure what the method does
but if you can break it in to few functions with numeric return value
you can hash them and improve it much more